# stream.collect(Collectors.toList()) vs Arrays.asList(stream.toArray())

Tags: java

Assuming:

- the mutability of the list is not important
- stream is a `Stream<Object>`

  stream.collect(Collectors.toList()) vs Arrays.asList(stream.toArray())

Which one is more performant?

Comment: Depends on what kind of "performance" you want to emphasize, really...

Comment: I would assume the latter is more performant. This is based on the facts that `Arrays.asList` is just a cheap wrapper, and that `Stream.toArray` is a specialized operation, unlike `Stream.collect`, which supports multiple mechanisms. Although, the difference is likely very insignificant, and the first one is a better option syntactically.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the stream knows the size, and most streams don't, the system cannot allocate the final array until all objects have been collected.

This means that `stream.toArray()` must first collect all the objects in a resizable container, e.g. an `ArrayList`, then create the array from that collection. Then you convert that array back to a list using `Arrays.asList()`.

Therefore, if you want a `List`, you should ask for a list, since you won't then waste time converting to array and back again.

Besides, if you want a `List`, you should ask for a list, to help clarify your code.

Example: Using `Arrays.asList(stream.toArray())` separates the `asList` and the `toArray` is the stream chain is large:

```
List<Foo> fooList = Arrays.asList(stream   // <-- asList way up here
        .filter(...)
        .map(...)
        .map(...)
        .filter(...)
        .toArray());                       // <-- toArray way down here
```

The same code using `toList()` is must clearer in intent:

```
List<Foo> fooList = stream
        .filter(...)
        .map(...)
        .map(...)
        .filter(...)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());     // <-- toList in one place
```

---

*Beware premature optimization.* Write the code for clarify and maintainability unless profiling shown you have a problem.

Of course, if the code runs in a tight loop where performance is paramount, your can optimize ahead of profiling.

But, if performance is that paramount, you wouldn't be using streams at all, because of the overhead of using streams.

Comment: I see many streams created from ArrayList’s so I don’t think its uncommon.

Comment: @Solubris Ehhh, what? This Q/A is about creating a `List` from a `Stream`, not about creating a `Stream` from an `ArrayList`.

Comment: If the stream is created from an ArrayList then it will have a known size so can be dealt with efficiently by toArray()

Comment: @Solubris Did you by any chance notice the use of `filter()` in my examples? You know, the common operation that makes any stream have unknown size? When I say "most streams", I'm referring to the stream seen by `toArray()`, not the original stream. Sure, if the purpose is to convert a `List<A>` into a `List<B>`, then you'd be right, but the use of the word "most" was deliberately chosen to allow for those too. I stand by the answer: Write for clarity. The overhead of using streams in the first place outweigh any micro-optimization gained from convoluted `Arrays.asList(stream.xxx.toArray())`.

Comment: It makes me wonder why the toArray() exists at all if it’s almost useless, and why the collector interface doesn’t allow for sizing the data structure if known..

Comment: @Solubris `toArray()` exists to allow you to get an array, if that is what you need. The real question is why they added `toArray()` to `Stream`, but not `toList()`. For consistency of API, it should have been `stream.collect(Collectors.toArray())`, not `stream.toArray()`.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays.asList doesn't return an java.util.ArrayList, rather it returns Arrays$ArrayList **which is backed by the same array**. The list is immutable. Add or Remove are unsupported operations. From the doc -:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)

Hence the better choice , in my opinion , is stream.collect.

Comment: *"The list is immutable"* Incorrect. It is fixed-size, but very mutable, hence the *"**Changes** to the returned list "write through""*. There can be no changes if it was truly immutable.

Comment: Besides, that's the wrong reason for choosing either, because the list returned by [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) may be immutable. Or not, it is undefined: *There are **no guarantees on** the type, **mutability**, serializability, or thread-safety **of the List returned***.